# How to custom stellar-core.cfg on docker quick start?

Tags: stellar-core, docker

I would like to change NETWORK_PASSPHRASE information in the stellar-core.cfg for my standalone network in order to get the new private seed for the genesis block. I managed to edit the file but when I try to restart the container the stellar-core is failed.  How could I do that?

## Example config file

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
RUN_STANDALONE=false
MANUAL_CLOSE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="**Change to somethings else**" 

KNOWN_CURSORS=["HORIZON"]
NODE_SEED="SDQVDISRYN2JXBS7ICL7QJAEKB3HWBJFP2QECXG7GZICAHBK4UNJCWK2 self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

#DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar user=postgres password=password host=localhost"
#DATABASE="sqlite3://stellar.db"
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=localhost user=stellar password=password"

COMMANDS=["ll?level=debug"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=100
VALIDATORS=["$self"]
```